# How can I get Offline Instller for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I recently try to install **Visual Studio 2017**.  But there is no offline installer.  How to get offline installer for it.
I also tried to install **Xamarin**.  Eventhough I have latest **Android SDK**, it ask me to download **Android SDK** again.  How to rectify it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce an offline installer you first need to download the corresponding online installer, which will give you an installation file similar to one of these:

- `vs_enterprise.exe` - Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, download [here](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_enterprise.exe)
- `vs_professional.exe` - Visual Studio 2017 Professional, download [here](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_professional.exe)
- `vs_community.exe` - Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, download [here](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_community.exe)

Then all you have to do is this:

```
vs_WHATEVER.exe --layout path-to-empty-directory
```

Example, to create an offline installer for Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition you first [download the online installer](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_community.exe), then you execute this:

```
vs_community.exe --layout d:\temp
```

This will fill `D:\Temp` with all the files necessary to install Visual Studio.

**Note:** The installer will open a console window as part of its process, you need to wait until this window closes before you can safely use the contents of this folder.

There will be many sub-directories, depending on the packages available, but you will also have the original executable you downloaded placed into this directory. Executing this from this directory will install using the provided packages.

Also note that by default, unless you manually specify `--add` and package id's, **all** the packages will be downloaded. You will thus get a complete and current version to install offline. However, if you specify packages with the `--add` parameter, **only** the specified packages will be downloaded.

[Source: Create a network installation of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio)